# Making my own shell

Tags: c, bash, shell, execv

This is homework, as you can tell. Which will be implemented in C.

First of all I created some functions that print the shell 
e.x.

```
printf("%s@cs345sh:~/%s ", getlogin(), get_working_directory());
```

After that, I proceed with tokenizing the input line with '|' as a delimiter so I get the commands that will be piped later on.

```
char* instr;
instr = strtok(line, "|");
while (instr != NULL) {
    insert_arguments_list(instr); //This is a singly-linked list that holds the arguments.
    instr = strtok(NULL, "|");
}
```

So now, I have to create a char *const array which is one of the things that I **don't** know how to do since all the variables have to be declared beforehand since it's const, no??

Can you provide some tips on how to proceed from now on?

Comment: What do you need that array for? What is the question?

Comment: no, you don't need to declare the variables as const, all of the exec() family casts const on their own. just concentrate on getting a char **[] populated with the sets of commands you needs from in between delimiters and then pass char *[]'s into execvp(). in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you want to use execv? The **execl** does the same thing and expects a const char* array of arguments.

`int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);`

Otherwise you are right, you can not assign the address to the char* const in runtime. That is why the **execl** is here - it is a convenient function for this purpose.

Comment: thank you for your response, this answers my first question. my other worry, is that I have an example input, ex: mkdir new_folder, i split that, in "mkdir" and "new_folder" and store them in an array, then parse that array?

Comment: Yes, your idea seem right to me. Your input may be either just mkdir folder, either mkdir folder1 folder2 or ls folder | grep regexp && mkdir folder and so on. It can become quite complex. The solution depends on what capabilities should your shell implement. You will parse the string and split the commands by | or && or other delimiters and those command will then contain  the name of the command and a list of the arguments, splitted by white character or just space.